# php regex error, unknown modifier 'd'

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Im trying to search for something on a page but i keep getting this silly error

this is the error i am getting

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'd'

this is the code im using

```
$qa = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
preg_match('/<a href="/download.php\?g=(?P<number>.+)">Click here</a>/',$qa,$result);
```

And $_GET['url'] can eqaul many things but in one case it was http://freegamesforyourwebsite.com/game/18-wheeler--2.html

the the html of that url basically

Anyone got a clue :S ? I dont even know where to start cus i dont know what a modifire is and the php.net site is no help

thankyou !

Comment: Everybody says escape, nobody mentions [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net/preg_quote), which is what you need. Sad, sad world....

Comment: @Wrikken, thank you for your comment!  This helped me solve a completely different problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the '/' before download.php otherwise it thinks you are ending your regex and providing 'd' as a modifier for your regex. You will also need to escape the next '/' in the ending anchor tag.

```
preg_match('/<a href="\/download.php\?g=(?P<number>.+)">Click here<\/a>/',$qa,$result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape your pattern delimiters or use different ones:

```
#                     v- escape the '/'
preg_match('/<a href="\/download.php\?g=(?P<number>.+)">Click here</a>/',$qa,$result);

#           v- use hatch marks instead
preg_match('#<a href="/download.php\?g=(?P<number>.+)">Click here</a>#',$qa,$result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression needs to be escaped correctly.

It should be:

```
'/<a href="\/download.php\?g=(?P<number>.+)">Click here<\/a>/'
```

Comment: Actually it should be: `'/<a href="\/download\.php\?g=(?P<number>.+)">Click here<\/a>/'`. You forgot to escape the "." in "download.php"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your regular expression is delimited by `/` characters, but also contains `/` characters as data. What it's complaining about is `/download` -- it thinks the `/` has ended your regular expression and the `d` that follows is a modifier for your regular expression. However, there is no such modifier `d`.

The easiest solution is to use some character that is not contained in the regex to delimit it. In this case, `@` would work well.

```
preg_match('@<a href="/download.php\?g=(?P<number>.+)">Click here</a>@',$qa,$result);
```